# better way then using vim :r! command line to put text out of the command line history like a directory path into the a file

Tags: command-line, vim, text-editors

Is there a better way to do this in vim

I like the command line completion that lets me quickly get a full path out. So I use the :!ls and tab to quickly get the path I am looking for.

> :!ls /usr/share/doc/
>   up arrow get it on the command line again, accessing the command line history.
>   :!ls /usr/share/doc/
>   Then I edit it like so
>   :r! echo "/usr/share/doc/"

Because I want to put the path into file and not the contents of the directory. 
Basically a quick way to put the contents of the command-line history into a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_command-line_history

also in vim the following is worth reading.

> :help cmdline-mode

Basically to paste the last command you ran you access the command register ":".

> ":p

To get a list of the last few commands you ran. You can then select from the history to rerun the command.

> q:

Answer (score 3):

(removed my stupid answer because I didn't read the question)

Hum, I should read questions more carefully.

Vim's Omni-complete gives you path completion.

Start with

```
/usr
```

then hit `<C-x><C-f>` to get a list of directories/files.

It works only for one level so you'll need to repeat the process until you get what you need.

Because `<C-x><C-f>` is not very friendly, I have it mapped to `,:`.

See `:help compl-filename`.

```
--EDIT--
```

In Vim, executing the following:

```
:!ls<CR><CR>
:r !echo !<CR>
```

puts `ls` in the buffer which seems to be what you are looking for.

In the terminal, type this to put the whole history of your shell session in a file:

```
$ history > history.txt
```

Comment: @romaninl +1 great for directories. Still want to see a way to get the command history out into a file.

Comment: Please, see my edit.